# What's the pronunciation of `tearDown` in jUnit?

Tags: pronunciation

There are `setup` and `tearDown` method in jUnit tests. What's the pronunciation of `tearDown`?

I found people pronounced it:

1. like t-ear
2. like t-air

Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> tear 
>        **/ tɛː/**
>       *verb*
>         1. pull (something) apart or to pieces with force.

---

> air
>   **/ɛː/**

So, 't-air'.

In the second meaning (eye secretion), Tear is /tɪə/ but unless the jUnit about getting someone to cry and have the method to have the tears drip down their cheeks, I think the first meaning is valid: *tear down* in meaning of *destroy* is pronounced as `t-air`.

Comment: I think in JUnit, tearDown() means dismantle(as a closest English meaning) and cleanup(as to what it actually does).

Answer (score 3):

In Java and some other programming languages, it's customary to form the single "word" needed by the computer by running together the words the programmer would use in a sentence. `tearDown` is simply a computer-acceptable formatting of the phrase **tear down** (meaning to disassemble or destroy), and is pronounced as the phrase. The pronunciation of **tear** can vary regionally.